# Nginx ingress not working - possibly ingressClass issue

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Just battling with a strange nginx ingress issue.  I had a config that was previously working on aks 1.22.6 but no longer working on 1.24+

Suspecting the issue is around the nginx ingress config as all works as expected hitting the services and pods when using port forwarding.

Here's my config that I'm applying:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: podinfo
  namespace: podinfo
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: mysubdomain.myk8sdemo.co.uk
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: podinfo
            port:
              number: 9898

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
spec:
  controller: k8s.io/ingress-nginx
```

The nginx ingress setup is being deployed via fluxcd gitops using the following setup.  Don't think the issue is anything gitops related and more to do with the ingress side of things, as was previously working on earlier AKS versions.

Been able to view the nginx running config and all looks good configured to my apps domain name.

```
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-system
spec:
  interval: 1m
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: ingress-nginx
      version: '4.0.13'
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: ingress-nginx
        namespace: flux-system
      interval: 1m
---
apiVersion: source.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: HelmRepository
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  interval: 30m
  url: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
```

Read some notes about the ingress class changing and moving from annotations to spec.ingressClassName.  Added this and also the IngressClass to see if that makes a difference but not able to access anything from the outside.

Looked in the nginx ingress logs and not seeing any errors in there.  Tried to track down the access logs but couldn't see anything on the ingress pod.

Anyone any ideas on where to go next as drawing a bit of a blank?